# Exisiting Tree Library in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Tree like structure were i have a root node and then i can add childrens to the root node and continue the process.  I am not really interested in sorting. All i want is a tree like structure since i am creating an Org Chart.

Is there an exisitng java library that will let me add root node, child node or for example get a child node from a tree and then add child to those nodes as well. Or maybe get all the leaf node from a tree.

I am trying to avoid creating one on my own just to save time ? Any libraries you can suggest will be of great help .

Note: I am not using Swing or AWT components.

Comment: Try look at java `TreeSet`

Comment: @RMachnik That's a Set implemented with an underlying tree, not really a useful tree :)
I'd suggest implementing one, it's just a matter of having a node class with a payload field and a list of children of the same class, plus a couple methods for manipulating it

Answer (score 5):

The `TreeModel` interface in Java is designed for this. [`DefaultTreeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html) supports adding any number of children to a node, listening on a node, and looking up nodes by path.

Comment: DefaultTreeModel is very nice, but it can not be used in Android projects.